# Microsoft Graph Create/Update a Tab EndPoint of SharePoint Document Library with Application permission returns Forbidden

Tags: microsoft-graph-api

Using Microsoft Graph API, the endpoint Create/Update a tab of Microsoft Teams returns a forbidden in some tenants. The issue can be replicated with Postman doing a simple call into the endpoint. This issue seems to be propagating as it’s failing in a few tenant already.
EndPoint: Add tab to channel (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/channel-post-tabs?view=graph-rest-1.0)
Our Application have all the required permissions documented (TeamsTab.Create.Group*, TeamsTab.Create, TeamsTab.ReadWriteSelfForTeam.All, TeamsTab.ReadWriteForTeam.All, TeamsTab.ReadWrite.All, Group.ReadWrite.All**, Directory.ReadWrite.All**)

[image: graph call returns forbidden]

The UI in Microsoft Teams is also broken, as you can’t click Next once you selected a Folder. The button is disabled.

[image: Teams UI fails too]